# Inconsistency Setting Word Margins/Column Spacing via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, ms-word, multiple-columns, margins, vba

Good Morning!

I am creating a tool to format many word documents with the same settings, and am working on setting all document body data to the column count specified, and the margins as specified. When run, this code works, but does not set the left/ right margins appropriately. The code should set each of them to the same value.

When run it seems to be variable. For instance, if I choose 0.3; the left margin will end of as 0.2 and the right will be 0.4. To make it a little weirder, if I manually go into the custom margin settings in MS Word, it states it is at the appropriate numbers (0.3) even when the margin bar on the page is not set there.

Has anyone worked with margins via vb to know if this is a setting issue, or if there is a more accurate way? I think it may have something to do with the column spacing .SpaceAfter = InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtColumnSpacing), but I am unsure.

Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub AddRemoveWatermark(strReplaceText As String)
    'Word Variables
    Dim wrdApplication As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDocument As Word.Document
    Dim wrdSection As Word.section
    Dim wrdSelection As Word.Selection
    Dim wrdHeader As Word.HeaderFooter
    Dim rngHeader As Word.Range
    Dim rngFooter As Word.HeaderFooter
    Dim spShape As Word.Shape

    Dim strDocumentName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strBBPath As String
    Dim lngCount As Long

    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

        Set wrdApplication = New Word.Application

        ' Display paths of each file selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            strPath = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
            Set wrdDocument = wrdApplication.Documents.Open(strPath)

            strDocumentName = wrdDocument.FullName 'Record the document name
            wrdApplication.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks

            wrdApplication.Visible = True

            'Document Layout
            If frmWordEdit.chkDocumentLayout.Value = True Then

                'Change Columns
                If frmWordEdit.chkColumns = True Then
                    With wrdDocument.PageSetup.TextColumns
                        .SetCount NumColumns:=frmWordEdit.txtColumns
                        '.Add EvenlySpaced:=True
                        '.Width = InchesToPoints(3)
                        '.SpaceAfter = InchesToPoints(0.3)
                    End With

                    Dim i As Integer

                    If frmWordEdit.txtColumns > 1 Then
                        For i = 1 To frmWordEdit.txtColumns - 1
                            With wrdDocument.PageSetup.TextColumns(i)
                                '.Width = InchesToPoints(4)
                                .SpaceAfter = InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtColumnSpacing)
                            End With

                        Next
                    End If
                End If

                'Change Margins
                If frmWordEdit.chkMargins = True Then
                    With wrdDocument.PageSetup
                        .LeftMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMLeftRight)
                        .RightMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMLeftRight)
                        .TopMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMTop)
                        .BottomMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMBottom)
                    End With
                End If

            End If

            'Document Design
            If frmWordEdit.chkDocumentDesign.Value = True Then
                If frmWordEdit.chkMHeader = True Then
                    With wrdDocument.PageSetup
                        .HeaderDistance = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMHeader)
                    End With
                End If

                If frmWordEdit.chkMFooter = True Then
                    With wrdDocument.PageSetup
                        .FooterDistance = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMFooter)
                    End With
                End If
            End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the part of your code which sets the margins.

> With wrdDocument.PageSetup
>     .LeftMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMLeftRight)
>     .RightMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMLeftRight)
>     .TopMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMTop)
>     .BottomMargin = wrdApplication.InchesToPoints(frmWordEdit.txtMBottom)
>
> End With

I find no fault with the syntax (except that you don't need to specify wrdApplication unless you run the code from another application, perhaps Excel). Since the code appears without fault errors must have their origin in the reference to frmWordEdit. I suggest that you run this code with plain numbers, expressed in points, and see if you still get the same result.
frmWordEdit.txtMLeftRight would appear to be a Textbox. Since you don't specify which property you are referring to it must be the default which is the Value property. The Value property of a Textbox holds a string which you feed into the InchesToPoints function. That function takes a single, if I'm not mistaken - anyway, a numeric value. Therefore I suspect that the string isn't correctly translated. Try something like InchesToPoints(Val(frmWordEdit.txtMLeftRight)).

Comment: I updated the code to use Val as it seems to be the better way to go, thank you. I did try to do it that way as well as direct point value and experienced the same issue. I think what may be happening is when it sets the .spaceafter to .3, it pulls the 2nd column to the left more, which increases the right margin. I believe the margin may actually be set to 0.3, but the column width isn't wide enough to meet it. That being said, I am trying to create a tool that can have variable inputs, and I don't know how to have the code adjust for the last column width in different situations.

Comment: I took a look at your code for setting the columns and found no obvious fault there either. Could it be that the total width of columns, including SpaceAfter, exceeds the total width of the page area as defined by the margins?